# Pivotal Cloud Foundry p2p communication between same application instances

Tags: spring-boot, hazelcast, p2p, cloud-foundry

Running spring boot app with hazelcast as member. When running several instances of app on local machine, hazelcast members are able to discover each other. I wonder how I can achieve same behavior between my app instances deploying on pcf. Just pushing app with 2 instances configured did not worked out. Have read [doc](https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/concepts/understand-cf-networking.html) on Container-to-container communication, but it seems to work for different apps communicating with each other, not for same app different instances.

Answer (score 2):

Container to container networking is your best bet. It allows you to talk between two different apps or between instances of the same app.

If you are trying to use multicast, I don't believe that works. You can open TCP & UDP connections between your apps and app instances though. By default, all ports and protocols are blocked, so make sure that you're opening the correct protocol/port combinations with `cf add-network-policy`.

https://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/2-4/devguide/deploy-apps/cf-networking.html#add-policy

To access the different instances of your application, you can use the polyglot service discovery functionality. It basically provides DNS for `X.<app-name>.apps.internal`. Where `X` is the instance number.

See the Clustering example here for details.

https://www.cloudfoundry.org/blog/polyglot-service-discovery-container-networking-cloud-foundry/

Hope that helps!

Comment: thanks for info on polyglot service, looks to be the way to go.

Comment: adding network policy for my application and using eureka server for member doscovery worked for me.  Some info here https://community.pivotal.io/s/question/0D50e0000529t0SCAQ/how-can-i-open-a-tcp-port-to-an-application Also I have run is some issues using internal routes for that purpose, since hazelcast could not resolve member addresses through internal routes. Though I found internal routes be very useful for other pursues.